# Remove duplicates from the table by using two columns in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have table like this

```
Id Name Lang   templateid
1  xxx  ENGISH  1
2  xxx  SPANISH 2
3  xxx  ENGISH  1
4  xxx  ENGISH  1
5  xxx  ENGISH  1
6  xxx  SPANISH 1
```

I want to remove the duplicate records which have same lang and templateid.For example templateid 1 + Lang ENGLISH is repeated more than once .

Delete the duplicates records and leave latest one ie., Id 5 is latest record for english language.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: No it doesn't comes under my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `MySQL`

**Query**

```
DELETE t2
FROM   tbl t1
JOIN   tbl t2 ON 
(
   t2.lang = t1.lang
   AND t2.templateId=t1.templateId
   AND t2.id < t1.id
);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/966cb3b/1)**

---

---

### `PostgreSQL`

**Query**

```
DELETE FROM tbl t1
WHERE id IN 
(
  SELECT t1.id
  FROM   tbl t1
  JOIN   tbl t2 ON 
  (
    t2.lang = t1.lang
    AND t2.templateId=t1.templateId
    AND t2.id > t1.id
  )
);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/977c6/1)**

Comment: When I run this query I am getting following exception  in postgres sql ERROR:  syntax error at or near "t2"
LINE 1: DELETE t2
               ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "t2"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 8

Comment: There is no chance for getting error dude. [check here for error details](http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-104_sqlstate_42601.html)

Comment: Thank you dude. Its working good in SQL but not in postgres sql . The error which I posted above is came from postgres sql.

Comment: Welcome dude. Please mark it as answer if that solved your problem.

Comment: Can you share the same query for postgres sql ?